# 'gli 80 €' vs. 'le 80 €'

Tags: articles

Si dice

> gli 80 €

o

> le 80 €

?

Il contesto è questo:

> Hai preso *gli/le* 80 € questo mese?

Comment: Penso che l'uso di "le" che ancora sopravvive nel caso di importi in denaro sia uno strascico di quando c'erano ancora le lire.

Comment: @Mir Probabile. Un altro uso con l'articolo femminile si ha quando si implica un sottinteso *banconote*, sempre che il taglio lo permetta: "hai preso le 50 Euro?" varrebbe per "hai preso le banconote da 50 Euro?".

Answer (score 13):

“Euro” è un sostantivo maschile e quindi l'articolo  corretto è **gli**. In realtà quando si  parla  di cifre in Euro generalmente non si usa l'articolo.

- ho speso 80 euro
- costa 20 euro,  etc.

Se ci si riferisce a una specifica somma – ad esempio, *gli ottanta euro che ti ho dato ieri* – si deve usare l'articolo maschile.

- Hai preso gli ottanta euro questo mese?

P.S. L'Euro non si usa mai al plurale. Può capitare di sentire ..gli Euri, ma si tratta di un errore o più probabilmente un uso scherzoso del termine.

Comment: In realtà ci sono anche motivi (oltre allo scherzo e all'errore) per difendere l'uso di “euri”. Comunque se n'è [già parlato](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/94/due-euro-vs-due-euri).

Answer (score 1):

La differenza tra `le` e `gli` è che Gli è la forma corretta. Con `le`, non ha senso perché `le` viene utilizzato **per tutti i nomi femminili**, ma euro è maschile.

Ex:

> **Le** ragazze sono così carine.

Con `gli`, ha senso perché è usato per i nomi maschili **che iniziano con una vocale** o con **z o s + consonante**.

Ex:

> Gli zii sono così divertenti.